# custom cert for only a few nodes of a WAS cluster

Tags: websphere, was

We have a peculiar WAS v85 environment and am trying to solve a cert/security ask from app team:

- One multi node cluster.
- Only half of them get live traffic, plugin tweaked to do so.
- cert at webserver layer for live traffic.
- Rest of the cluster member process batch jobs and get traffic directly from a Loadbalancer (no webserver in between and uses unsecured url).

Now, there is a need for this batch servers to process some new load which needs a secured url.
How can I add internal signed personal cert to just the batch nodes and make sure the current live servers do not get disturbed?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously test this somewhere before you go to your production.

Based on your description I will assume you have WebSphere Application Server Network Deployment version 8.5.5.x

From the WebSphere Application Server administrative console,
Under Security, SSL certificate and key management, Key stores and certificates...

Create a new SSL keystore with the certificates you want to use
Copy the Path information from the CellDefaultKeyStore, for my system it is:
${CONFIG_ROOT}/cells/wrhrhelCell01/
your cell name will be different.
Push the New... button fill in a name for a new keystore that you can relate to like BatchJobKeyStore and put the path information in the Path edit box with batchkey.p12 appended to it, for example: ${CONFIG_ROOT}/cells/wrhrhelCell01/batchkey.p12
Enter the Password you want to use, I just use the same as the default "WebAS", leave the rest defaults and press OK, and then Save to the master configuration.
Select BatchJobKeyStore, then Personal certificates, on the Create button select the Chained Certificate... type default for the Alias and then keep the root of the cell selected and the keysize at 2048.  Type the hostname in the Common name and set the validity period to 3650 days (10 years or whatever you need) Type your cell name in the Organization and then type BatchJobs and type the state you are in like North Carolina and the zipcode and select Country or region like US... and finally push OK and Save it.

Now create a new SSL configuration ...

From the WebSphere Application Server administrative console,
Under Security, SSL certificate and key management, Key stores and certificates...

Select SSL configurations, and push the New... button Type BatchJobsSettings make sure the trust store name is the CellDefaultTrustStore (You usually have to change it) set the Keystore name to BatchJobKeyStore (the new one you created) and leave the rest of the defaults and press OK and save it.

Now map the new configuration to the nodes where the batchjobs are running.

From the WebSphere Application Server administrative console,
Under Security, SSL certificate and key management, Key stores and certificates...

Select Manage endpoint security configurations, start under the Inbound tree, select the nodes that are running the Batch jobs, or if you have to go lower select the server and check the box for Override inherited values and select the new one you made BatchJobSettings and do the same under the Outbound tree. Save it and Sync it and restart everything.

You will need to call the protected port now, so if they were using the default 9080 then they would need to use  something like 9443

Comment: Great, thanks for the quick response. I do have a test environment to test this out.